# Novel about undead skeletons killing people to create more skeletons

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

Can anybody help me identify this book?  I think it was called Skeletons.  It was about the dead rising and coming back as skeletons of themselves and killing the living to make more skeleton people.  Abraham Lincoln resumes presidency of the US.  Among the surviving people is a pregnant woman whose baby dies, becomes a skeleton and pierces its way out of her womb, causing her to also become a skeleton

Comment: And you are sure this was *fiction*? Try the History Stack Exchange also, just to cover all bases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Skeletons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2409040.Skeletons)* by Al Sarrantonio

> In Moscow, the sound of bones echoes across Red Square. In America, skeletons patrol the streets of Manhattan and blood stains the confields of the Midwest. While in Washington, D. C., Abraham Lincoln is heading for his third term in the White House.
>
> The best -- and worst -- of humanity are back with a vengeance, a skeletal army hell-bent on conquering the living and uniting the world under the banner of the dead.
>
> Against this bloody backdrop of global horror, a small group of refugees find themselves drawn together by a single vision and a shared fate: to determine whether the last two humans on earth will survive or join the ranks of the newly risen.
>
> SKELETONS
>
> Terrifying and outrageous, Skeletons is a roller coaster ride into the fibrillating heart of darkness by one of horror's scariest writers.

Found with a search for *novel skeletons "Abraham Lincoln"*

Comment: Ok. It's pretty amusing that the name of the novel about skeletons turns out to be "Skeletons"

Comment: It's nice when your working title manages to become the actual title.