# A spaceship approaches the Earth carrying living skeletons that convert the living into more skeletons by pushing them through a transformation arc

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

If a skeleton passes through the arc again, they're transformed back into human form.

Ultimately, the main character is the last man standing and he prevails by pulling *two* skeletons along with him through the transformation arc, thus setting a geometric progression in motion to save the day.

I read this 30+ years ago and it was in a book so presumably an anthology. It is not "[Skeletons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2409040.Skeletons)" by Al Sarrantonio, as this story all takes place on the spaceship.

Comment: [Where "Skeletons" was the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/novel-about-undead-skeletons-killing-people-to-create-more-skeletons/220315#220315) for people thinking 'we had this before..."

Comment: It was a memorable story, but I don't remember the author of the title either. I read it in Polish translation.